# Instructions Per Count (IPC) and Instruction Level Parallelism (ILP) in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I observe `IPC` drops as `ILP` goes up for `32-bit int` operations when trying to speed up my cryptographic kernel. The kernel consists of fairly unrolled loops of long sequence of `ADD` and `XOR` operations, which should have a throughput of `160 ops` per `192` cores per cycle on Kepler (`GTX Titan/780`).

`IPC` for my kernel hits the upper bound of `3.28`. Using `ILP` even drops `IPC`. Apparently `ILP` fails to help achieve my goal -- fully utilize the pipeline, so I wrote some little experiments. I put the code for `ILP 4` at the end.

### Profiler Measurements

- Results are measured on GTX Titan.
- `cubin` outputs are examined to make sure no instructions are eliminated during optimization.
- `Executed IPC` is almost the same as issued `IPC`, so I just list one of them.

**ADD instructions** (`XOR`s have identical behavior)

```
             | ILP 1  | ILP 2   | ILP 4  | ILP 8
--------------------------------------------------
 IPC         |   4.00 |   3.32  |   2.72 |   3.44
--------------------------------------------------
 Issue Slot  | 99.17% | 59.34%  | 48.61% | 61.71%
 Utilization |        |         |        |
```

- I expect `ILP` `2`, `4` and `8` would give better performance, but not.
- Recall the integer throughput is `160`. The `4` warp scheduler per SM should dual issue up to `5` instructions per cycle, so that `IPC` should go up towards `5`. How can I explain what I observed? Why is the issue slot 99% utilized when `IPC = 4`?

**Float / Int ADD instruction mix**

If I modify the code for `ILP 4` to do two `int` `ADD`s and two `float` `ADD`s:

```
IPC: 5.1
Issue slot utilization: 99.12%
```

Strangely enough, it seems that the warp scheduler does a better job to issue floating operations.

### Discussion

- Available literature suggests using `ILP` help reach the peak performance for floating point operations. Why doesn't `ILP` apply to integers? How can I do this for integer operations?
- My kernel theoretically should do `2.25` integer operations per candidate. This is consistent with what I observed in `cuobjdump`. There are `2^48` candidates, so the minimun runtime on GTX Titan should be `2.25 * 2^48 / (2688 * 160/192) / 876 MHz = 322.75s`. Is this estimation reasonable?
- The measured performance for my kernel is `523s`. This does imply that integer throughput is only about `160 * 3.28 (measure IPC) / 5 (max IPC)`.

### ILP test code

```cpp
__device__ int x[10];
__global__ void test(int flag = 0)
{
    int a = x[0], b = x[1], c = x[2], d = x[3];
    int _a = x[4], _b = x[5], _c = x[6], _d = x[7];

#pragma unroll 128
    for (int i = 0; i < 51200; ++i)
    {
        asm volatile("add.u32 %0, %0, %1;": "+r"(a): "r"(_a));
        asm volatile("add.u32 %0, %0, %1;": "+r"(b): "r"(_b));
        asm volatile("add.u32 %0, %0, %1;": "+r"(c): "r"(_c));
        asm volatile("add.u32 %0, %0, %1;": "+r"(d): "r"(_d));
    }

    int v = a + b + c + d;
    if (flag * v == 1)
        x[0] = v;
}
```

### Code fragment for 4 candidates

Each candidate takes `9 / 4 = 2.25` ops. `Cuobjdump` also verifies this.

```cpp
d ^= d2(1, 3);                 // d2 is located in constant memory
s ^= d;
t ^= d2(1, 16);
u ^= d2(1, 17);
v ^= some_const;
flag_s = min(flag_s, s);       // int min has throughput of 160
flag_t = flag_t || (s == t);   // setp.or should be the same
flag_u = flag_u || (s == u);
flag_v = flag_v || (s == v);
```

Comment: Maybe ILP gain is valid for multi pipelined ALUd and multi pipelined FPUd cores such as fermi(seems more heavy weight) and vliw5(for special function unit).

Comment: Mixing all 32bitInt 32bitfp 64bitInt 64bitfp thread shuffle/bittwiddling can give fully pipelined computing and overlapping asynchronous kernels can make use of GPU @ %100.

Comment: Thanks! I agree mixing instructions can give full utilization. But for kernels that involves only int ops, and is not at all memory bound, is there an example that can achieve (near) 100% performance?

Answer (score 2):

I'm providing an answer to remove this question from the unanswered list.

I do not observe a change in `executed Instructions Per Count` (`IPC`) with `Instruction Level Parallelism`. Overall, it is difficult to argue the reason for the effect observed by the OP without knowing any further information but that provided by the OP himself (f.i., the launch configuration).

In the code below, I'm considering an example using `float`s, although I have tested the same code with `int`s without changing the conceptual results. The code implements cyclical `Multiply Add` (`MAD`) operations with `ILP=1`, `ILP=2` and `ILP=4`.

The `executed IPC` has been the following

```
ILP         IPC            FLOPs
1           3.924          67108864
2           4.323          67108864
4           4.016          67108864
```

for `N=8192`. The code has been compiled with `CUDA 8.0` and run on an `NVIDIA GT920M`. As it can be seen, `IPC` keeps almost constant for the differently considered values of `ILP`. The `Floating Point Operations` (`FLOP`s) as estimated by the code assuming `2` `FLOP`s per `MAD` coincides with that measured by the Visual Profiler.

**THE CODE**

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define N_ITERATIONS 8192

#include "Utilities.cuh"
#include "TimingGPU.cuh"

#define BLOCKSIZE   512

//#define DEBUG

/********************************************************/
/* KERNEL0 - NO INSTRUCTION LEVEL PARALLELISM (ILP = 0) */
/********************************************************/
__global__ void kernel0(float * __restrict__ d_a, const float * __restrict__ d_b, const float * __restrict__ d_c, const int N) {

    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tid < N) {

        float a = d_a[tid];
        float b = d_b[tid];
        float c = d_c[tid];

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N_ITERATIONS; i++) {
            a = a * b + c;
        }

        d_a[tid] = a;
    }

}

/*****************************************************/
/* KERNEL1 - INSTRUCTION LEVEL PARALLELISM (ILP = 2) */
/*****************************************************/
__global__ void kernel1(float * __restrict__ d_a, const float * __restrict__ d_b, const float * __restrict__ d_c, const int N) {

    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tid < N / 2) {

        float a1 = d_a[tid];
        float b1 = d_b[tid];
        float c1 = d_c[tid];

        float a2 = d_a[tid + N / 2];
        float b2 = d_b[tid + N / 2];
        float c2 = d_c[tid + N / 2];

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N_ITERATIONS; i++) {
            a1 = a1 * b1 + c1;
            a2 = a2 * b2 + c2;
        }

        d_a[tid] = a1;
        d_a[tid + N / 2] = a2;
    }

}

/*****************************************************/
/* KERNEL2 - INSTRUCTION LEVEL PARALLELISM (ILP = 4) */
/*****************************************************/
__global__ void kernel2(float * __restrict__ d_a, const float * __restrict__ d_b, const float * __restrict__ d_c, const int N) {

    const int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    if (tid < N / 4) {

        float a1 = d_a[tid];
        float b1 = d_b[tid];
        float c1 = d_c[tid];

        float a2 = d_a[tid + N / 4];
        float b2 = d_b[tid + N / 4];
        float c2 = d_c[tid + N / 4];

        float a3 = d_a[tid + N / 2];
        float b3 = d_b[tid + N / 2];
        float c3 = d_c[tid + N / 2];

        float a4 = d_a[tid + 3 * N / 4];
        float b4 = d_b[tid + 3 * N / 4];
        float c4 = d_c[tid + 3 * N / 4];

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N_ITERATIONS; i++) {
            a1 = a1 * b1 + c1;
            a2 = a2 * b2 + c2;
            a3 = a3 * b3 + c3;
            a4 = a4 * b4 + c4;
        }

        d_a[tid] = a1;
        d_a[tid + N / 4] = a2;
        d_a[tid + N / 2] = a3;
        d_a[tid + 3 * N / 4] = a4;
    }

}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    //const int N = 8192 * 64;
    const int N = 8192;
    //const int N = 1024;

    TimingGPU timerGPU;

    float *h_a = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
    float *h_a_result_host = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
    float *h_a_result_device = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
    float *h_b = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
    float *h_c = (float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));

    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
        h_a[i] = 2.;
        h_b[i] = 1.;
        h_c[i] = 2.;
        h_a_result_host[i] = h_a[i];
        for (unsigned int k = 0; k < N_ITERATIONS; k++) {
            h_a_result_host[i] = h_a_result_host[i] * h_b[i] + h_c[i];
        }
    }

    float *d_a; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a, N*sizeof(float)));
    float *d_b; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_b, N*sizeof(float)));
    float *d_c; gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc((void**)&d_c, N*sizeof(float)));

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_b, h_b, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_c, h_c, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    /***********/
    /* KERNEL0 */
    /***********/
    timerGPU.StartCounter();
    kernel0 << <iDivUp(N, BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE >> >(d_a, d_b, d_c, N);
#ifdef DEBUG
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
#endif
    // --- Remember: timing is in ms
    printf("Number of operations = %f; GFlops = %f\n", (float)N*(float)N_ITERATIONS, (1.e-6)*((float)N*(float)N_ITERATIONS) / timerGPU.GetCounter());
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_a_result_device, d_a, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++) if (h_a_result_device[i] != h_a_result_host[i]) { printf("Error at i=%i! Host = %f; Device = %f\n", i, h_a_result_host[i], h_a_result_device[i]); return 1; }

    /***********/
    /* KERNEL1 */
    /***********/
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    timerGPU.StartCounter();
    kernel1 << <iDivUp(N / 2, BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE >> >(d_a, d_b, d_c, N);
#ifdef DEBUG
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
#endif
    // --- Remember: timing is in ms
    printf("Number of operations = %f; GFlops = %f\n", (float)N*(float)N_ITERATIONS, (1.e-6)*((float)N*(float)N_ITERATIONS) / timerGPU.GetCounter());
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_a_result_device, d_a, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++) if (h_a_result_device[i] != h_a_result_host[i]) { printf("Error at i=%i! Host = %f; Device = %f\n", i, h_a_result_host[i], h_a_result_device[i]); return 1; }

    /***********/
    /* KERNEL2 */
    /***********/
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    timerGPU.StartCounter();
    kernel2 << <iDivUp(N / 4, BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE >> >(d_a, d_b, d_c, N);
#ifdef DEBUG
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
#endif
    // --- Remember: timing is in ms
    printf("Number of operations = %f; GFlops = %f\n", (float)N*(float)N_ITERATIONS, (1.e-6)*((float)N*(float)N_ITERATIONS) / timerGPU.GetCounter());
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_a_result_device, d_a, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++) if (h_a_result_device[i] != h_a_result_host[i]) { printf("Error at i=%i! Host = %f; Device = %f\n", i, h_a_result_host[i], h_a_result_device[i]); return 1; }

    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;

}
```